# python tkinter drawing program

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I've got 2 separate programs, both I got from Stack Overflow, and both works on their own. here is the first:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import os

    w, h = 500, 200

    # Add a couple widgets. We're going to put pygame in `embed`.
    root = tk.Tk()
    embed = tk.Frame(root, width=w, height=h)
    embed.pack()
    text = tk.Button(root, text='Blah.')
    text.pack()

    # Tell pygame's SDL window which window ID to use    
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())

    # The wxPython wiki says you might need the following line on Windows
    # (http://wiki.wxpython.org/IntegratingPyGame).
    #os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

    # Show the window so it's assigned an ID.
    root.update()

    # Usual pygame initialization
    import pygame as pg
    pg.display.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((w,h))

    pos = 0
    while 1:
        # Do some pygame stuff
        screen.fill(pg.Color(0,0,0))
        pos = (pos + 1) % screen.get_width()
        pg.draw.circle(screen, pg.Color(255,255,255), (pos,100), 30)

        # Update the pygame display
        pg.display.flip()

        # Update the Tk display
        root.update()
```

this program should embed a pygame window into a tkinter frame, it works like a charm, here is the second program:

```
    import pygame, random

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    draw_on = False
    last_pos = (0, 0)
    color = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255,255,255)
    radius = 10
    screen.fill(white)

    def roundline(srf, color, start, end, radius=1):
        dx = end[0]-start[0]
        dy = end[1]-start[1]
        distance = max(abs(dx), abs(dy))
        for i in range(distance):
            x = int( start[0]+float(i)/distance*dx)
            y = int( start[1]+float(i)/distance*dy)
            pygame.draw.circle(srf, color, (x, y), radius)

    try:
        while True:
            e = pygame.event.wait()
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                raise StopIteration
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, e.pos, radius)
                draw_on = True
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                draw_on = False
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if draw_on:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, e.pos, radius)
                    roundline(screen, color, e.pos, last_pos,  radius)
                last_pos = e.pos
            pygame.display.flip()

    except StopIteration:
      pass

 pygame.quit()
```

the second should display a pygame screen on which you can draw anything you like.

I am not a very experienced pygame programmer however, I have experience using tkinter. What I want to do is make a program on which you can draw, but it also have to have tkinter buttons, entry's etc.

both programs works perfectly fine alone, however, when I want to replace the pygame part in the first program, everything works fine except, I cannot draw anything, the button doesn't want to be clicked, and I can't exit via x, that does not make sense at all, so I'm thinking that maybe there is something wrong, anyway, I can't find the problem so I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Just saying, you really shouldn't be raising exceptions and using try-catch to break out of loops

Comment: ok, il take it out, i did not put it there though, it was what i got from the program, i just downloaded it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actualy figured the answer out myself, the reason i used pygame is becouse i didnt think you could use tkinter, but i made a program that uses tkinter and actuely draws quite good (maybe better than pygame) i will add this program

```
    from tkinter import *


    b1 = "up"
    xold, yold = None, None
    display_width = '500'
    display_height = '500'
    canvas_width = '500'
    canvas_height = '500'
    def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry((display_width+"x"+display_height))


        drawing_area = Canvas(root,width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height,bg="white")
        drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", motion)
        drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", b1down)
        drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", b1up)
        drawing_area.pack(side=RIGHT)
        root.mainloop()

    def b1down(event):
        global b1
        x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
        x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
        event.widget.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black" )
        b1 = "down"           # you only want to draw when the button is down
                              # because "Motion" events happen -all the time-

    def b1up(event):
        global b1, xold, yold
        b1 = "up"
        xold = None           # reset the line when you let go of the button
        yold = None

    def motion(event):
        if b1 == "down":
            global xold, yold
            x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
            x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
            event.widget.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black" )
            if xold is not None and yold is not None:
                python_green = "#476042"
                x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
                x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
                event.widget.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black" )
                event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE,width=9)
                              # here's where you draw it. smooth. neat.
            xold = event.x
            yold = event.y

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

this program is different from other canvas drawing programs becouse it uses both lines and ovals, minimizing chances of gaps in your lines, thanks for anyone who viewed this, i hope you found this useful